# Assign value to session variable using javascript

Tags: javascript, session, session-variables

I am developing an asp.net web application. I need to use java script to assign variables to the session variable. How can i use javascript to assign a value to a session variable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot set session variables directly from Javascript. However you can use Ajax to set session variables. Pass the value to be set to a web method which sets it and it will become accessible as a session variable.